# How to load csv Col value in javascript variable for conditional looping in Imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

Is there any way to have access on csv data loaded in imacros. I want to load Col value on a js variable and then perform some check on it.

like.

```
var colValue = ~column 3 value in current loop~;
```

I read some syntax on this website. that uses

```
var colValue = {{!COL1}};
```

but it was not worked for me. showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you need something like this:

```
const L = "\n";
var M = "SET !DATASOURCE somefile.csv" + L;
M += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1" + L;
M += "SET !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + L;
iimPlayCode(M);
var colValue = iimGetExtract(1);
```